# Any bubbles simulation + Eevee Tutorials?

Tags: particles, physics

I am actually trying to make steam from a hot drink cup. But in a cartoon style. This is the reason I am not using the Smoke simulator. So maybe the Particle System settings for soap bubbles would do, I would just replace the bubbles with my own meshes. 
Needless to say I have searched and searched only to find old tutorials for Cycles and even Blender Internal.
Could anyone care to share a tutorial on making floating thingies (not necessarily bubbles)? I am only interested in the Particle System/Physics workflow and settings.
Thanks a bunch in advance guys :slight_smile:

Cheers!

Comment: Hi. Asking for tutorials is [off-topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) but you are welcome to ask the actual question here (although ideally you would show what you have tried and where *specifically* you are getting stuck, otherwise the answer itself would have to be tutorial sized). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the basics and take it from there… (hopefully it will help someone).

Basic Settings, as in Barebone settings

Requirements:

Domain - This is the container where the simulation will happen.
Use a cube, adapt it to the dimensions of the simulation. E.g. if it is for something that will float or elevate (like smoke) then a vertical rectangle would do.
While the cube is selected, go to the Physics Properties tab from the Properties right panel.
Enable Physics for: Fluid, type: Domain, Settings: Domain Type: Gas, everything else stays untouched for now.

Force Field - Inside the cube, at the bottom add a plane. While the cube is selected, go to the Physics Properties tab add a Force Field to it. Type: Wind, Settings: Shape: Plane, Strength: 0.700, Flow: 0.500, everything else stays untouched for now.

Particles Emitter - Inside the cube, above the Force Field plane, add a 2nd plane. While the cube is selected, go to the Physics Properties tab. Fluid, Type: Flow, Settings: Flow Type: Liquid, Flow Behavior: Geometry, everything else stays untouched for now.
Also add a Particle System to the same plane - From the tab above, the Particle Properties, click the “+” sign in the upper-right corner to add it. It will be called “ParticleSettings”. Keep it as an Emitter. Change the Number of particles to whatever suits your simulation. Emission/Number: Default is 1000. I had enough with 100. Check when you want them to end, default is at the frame 200. Check for how many frames they will live, default is: 50 frames. Cache (Optional, if your RAM can afford it): Cache Step: 6, this will smooth the simulation. Rotation (Optional): checked, Randomize: 0.5.
Physics: Newtonian, Mass: 0.5.
Multiply Mass with Size: checked.
Default shape of particles is Halo (little spheres). To change it to an object of your choice: Render section of the same tab, Render As: Object, Scale: 1.000, Object, Instance Object: “your obj here”.